# rvest how to select a specific css node by id

Tags: html, css, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to use the rvest package to scrape data from a web page. In a simple format, the html code looks like this:

```
<div class="style">
   <input id="a" value="123">
   <input id="b">
</div>
```

I want to get the value 123 from the first input. I tried the following R code:

```
library(rvest)
url<-"xxx"
output<-html_nodes(url, ".style input")
```

This will return a list of input tags:

```
[[1]]
<input id="a" value="123">
[[2]]
<input id="b">
```

Next I tried using html_node to reference the first input tag by id:

```
html_node(output, "#a")
```

Here it returned a list of nulls instead of the input tag I want.

```
[[1]]
NULL
[[2]]
NULL
```

My question is, how can I reference the input tag using its id?

Answer (score 40):

You can use xpath:

```
require(rvest)
text <- '<div class="style">
   <input id="a" value="123">
   <input id="b">
</div>'

h <- read_html(text)

h %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="a"]') %>%
  xml_attr("value")
```

The easiest way to get css- and xpath-selector is to use http://selectorgadget.com/.
For a specific attribute like yours use chrome's developer toolbar to get the xpath as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

This will work just fine with straight CSS selectors:

```
library(rvest)

doc <- '<div class="style">
   <input id="a" value="123">
   <input id="b">
</div>'

pg <- html(doc)
html_attr(html_nodes(pg, "div > input:first-of-type"), "value")

## [1] "123"
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding an answer bc I don't see the easy css selector shorthand for selecting by id: using `#your_id_name`:

```
h %>% 
  html_node('#a') %>%
  html_attr('value')
```

which outputs "123" as desired.

Same setup as the others:

```
require(rvest)
text <- '<div class="style">
   <input id="a" value="123">
   <input id="b">
</div>'

h <- read_html(text)
```