# Scrape all div tags id (not their value) with similar format

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I have a internal company html webpage with a `div` html tag having the following format:

```
<div id="B4_6_2019">
<div id="B3_6_2019">
```

I would like to extract all the id names so the end result would be 
    B4_6_2019
    B3_6_2019

How would I do that? (the id names are all dates)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rvest how to select a specific css node by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127921/rvest-how-to-select-a-specific-css-node-by-id)

Comment: I dont think so. The other one is for scraping the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("div") %>%
  html_attr("id") %>%
  grep("^B\\d+_\\d+_\\d+", ., value = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try also attribute = value css selector with ends with operator to substring match on end of id value string

```
library(rvest)
page <- read_html("url")
id<- page %>% 
  html_nodes("[id$='_2019']") %>%
  html_attr(., "id")
```